Expo EAS build android APK crash on physical device (Expo 51)
I built eas build -p android --profile production(with Expo SDK 51, The build was successful without any problems). Then, I downloaded apk into physical device. When install and open it, the app crashes after showing splash screen.
There's nothing wrong with the simulator and the expo go app
So I connected the physical device to the PC and tried again as below
1. eas build -p android --profile production --clear-cache
2. adb install -r MyApp.apk
3. adb logcat

But the app crashes after showing splash screen again.
I found exceptions in Logcat's log as below.
06-18 15:16:23.359  1455  3526 W WindowManager: Exception thrown during dispatchAppVisibility Window{b491ce8 u0 com.myApp.MyApp/com.myApp.MyApp.MainActivity EXITING}

06-18 15:35:37.566  1455  1567 W PackageManager: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to get package com.myApp.MyApp

06-18 15:35:38.323 18370 18370 W Finsky  : [2] aegq.b(126): STU: Failed to get storage stats for package 'com.myApp.MyApp' (1601: Error getting stats: android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException)

06-18 15:57:18.002 25857 25946 W GOS:PackageUtil: isPackageInstalledAsUser(). Exception: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.myApp.MyApp

06-18 15:57:53.221  1455  2981 W WindowManager: Exception thrown during dispatchAppVisibility Window{1ccb0a5 u0 com.myApp.MyApp/com.myApp.MyApp.MainActivity EXITING}

06-18 15:58:02.730  1455  6310 E AppOps  : java.lang.SecurityException: Specified package "com.myApp.MyApp" under uid -1 but it is not

06-18 16:06:54.320 26999 26999 E AppButtonsPrefCtl: Exception when retrieving package:com.myApp.MyApp

06-18 16:06:54.320 26999 26999 E AppButtonsPrefCtl: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.myApp.MyApp

06-18 16:06:54.537 18370 18612 W ResourcesManager: java.io.IOException: Failed to load asset path /data/app/~~DvIivdyMBKmqze5UOR38yA==/com.myApp.MyApp-djdb_-FbcxNuzhRd3BN9Dw==/base.apk

Can someone tell or direct or advice me?
Here is my app.json, eas.json and package.json

app.json

{
  "expo": {
    "name": "MyApp",
    "slug": "MyApp",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "scheme": "myapp",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.myApp.MyApp",
      "buildNumber": "1.0.0"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.myApp.MyApp",
      "versionCode": 1
    },
    "web": {
      "bundler": "metro",
      "output": "static",
      "favicon": "./assets/images/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "expo-router",
      "expo-font"
    ],
    "experiments": {
      "typedRoutes": true,
      "tsconfigPaths": true
    },
    "extra": {
      "router": {
        "origin": false
      },
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
      }
    }
  }
}


eas.json

{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 9.2.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}



package.json

{
  "name": "myApp",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "8.0.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.7.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.43.1",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.36.0",
    "expo": "^51.0.14",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-device": "~6.0.2",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.7",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.28.9",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.16",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.6",
    "expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.51.3",
    "react-native": "0.74.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^17.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-select-dropdown": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-url-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~51.0.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}



This issue was due to environmental variables. It was caused by the failure to load environmental variables in the build. Make sure the environmental variables are loaded properly.
